# GET request error 404 (not found) using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, vercel

I have a problem with my nextjs pizzashop application. When i run the app on my computer i get this error :

[image]

The error goes away after the page refreshes.

### This is my `index.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useState } from "react";
import Add from "../components/Add";
import AddButton from "../components/AddButton";
import Featured from "../components/Featured";
import PizzaList from "../components/PizzaList";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home({ pizzaList }) {
  const [close, setClose] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Pizza Restaurant in New york</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Best pizza shop in town" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Featured />
      {<AddButton setClose={setClose} style={{ display: "none" }} />}
      <PizzaList pizzaList={pizzaList} />
      {!close && <Add setClose={setClose} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  const myCookie = ctx.req?.cookies || "";
  let admin = false;

  if (myCookie.token === process.env.TOKEN) {
    admin = true;
  }

  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
  return {
    props: {
      pizzaList: res.data,
      admin,
    },
  };
};
```

When i upload the application to vercel i get this error :

[image]

### This is the error I'm getting in vercel server runtime

[image]

[image]

### This is my /api/products/[id].js file code

```
import dbConnect from "../../../util/mongo";
import Product from "../../../models/Product";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const {
    method,
    query: { id },
    cookies,
  } = req;
  const token = cookies.token;

  await dbConnect();

  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const product = await Product.findById(id);
      res.status(200).json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }

  if (method === "PUT") {
    if (!token || token !== process.env.token) {
      return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");
    }
    try {
      const product = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {
        new: true,
      });
      res.status(200).json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }

  if (method === "DELETE") {
    if (!token || token !== process.env.token) {
      return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");
    }
    try {
      await Product.findByIdAndDelete(id);
      res.status(200).json("The product has been deleted!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
}
```

### This is my /api/products/index.js file code

```
import dbConnect from "../../../util/mongo";
import Product from "../../../models/Product";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method, cookies } = req;

  const token = cookies.token;

  await dbConnect();

  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
      const products = await Product.find();
      res.status(200).json(products);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }

  if (method === "POST") {
    if (!token || token !== process.env.token) {
      return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");
    }
    try {
      const product = await Product.create(req.body);
      res.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect the error is coming from my get request but i cannot diagnose why. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, data or errors. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Do you have an example of the server-side code? From the looks of it that route does not exist, so I'm guessing you either didn't create the `/api/products` route on the server or you misconfigured it

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the server side application can be set up as separate deployment. In that case, you can simply follow something similar to what is given here: https://vercel.com/guides/handling-node-request-body

Instead of sending a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/products`, you can use the deployment url for the server side code like `http://some-deployment-url/api/products` to access the data you require.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: If it is a part of the same app, try using your app's deploy url only